# ios How to detect and perminantly set UIButton State for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parsing, uibutton

I am trying to implement a like feature into my app such as Facebook, Instagram etc.

I have a newsfeed that is made with UITableViewCells to display my content.

Within each of my cells, there is a like button, that when the user taps I want to update my front end and backend.

I know how to update my backend, the problem is detecting what state the button is in.

**Here are the steps I am trying to take:**

--> User taps like button on UITableViewCell (Done)

--> Method calls (Done)

--> Detect if button is already liked / selected (Don't know how to do)

--> Update front end and save to backend (Done)

The big challenge is if I set a button to UIStateSelected, the button is temporarily selected but then **since the cells are reused, The button will get replaced.**

**I don't want to check every time with the backend** if the user has liked it or not, because there is delay checking things over the internet.

The only other option I have thought of is **creating a temporary array**, but I've thought since **users could be liking 100's of posts fairly fast**, storing temporary arrays could get messy and costly...

So what is the best way to be able to keep temporary track of user likes with the front end of my app, e.g I like a post, scroll down to the bottom of feed, scroll back up and that post is still liked?

Thanks for everyones help!

Comment: Have you worked with tags?

Comment: Yes how would it be practical in this situation?

Comment: Well, you can store array of int's of tags, and then set them selected in that indexPath.row. This is just proposal, I haven't implemented this kind of solution.